# Помощь с дискорд ботом python

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Пишу уже давно дискорд-бота, есть различные функции. Начал пробовать добавить воспроизведение музыки в голосовые каналы и не получается, возможно вы сможете мне помочь...

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import youtube_dl
import pafy
import asyncio
import requests
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import psutil
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import uptime
import logging
import ffmpeg

import aiohttp

 @bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        return await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому каналу!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        vc = ctx.voice_client

    video = pafy.new(url)
    best = video.getbestaudio()
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(best.url, method='fallback')

    vc.play(source)
```

Не знаю, что конкретно скинуть, но в общем оно не работает, выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on
> https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version;
> see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call
> youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

А так же огромную ошибку в консоль (настолько большая что сюда не помещается)